# C# Select XML Attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I want to select some Attributes out of a Node in XML with C#.
My XML Looks like this:

```
<itemdata>
   <items>
      <item id="1" name="table">
         <cost>200</cost>
         <category>5</category>
         <type>2</type>
      </item>
      <item id="2" name="chair">
         <cost>100</cost>
         <category>4</category>
         <type>6</type>
      </item>
      <item id="3" name="lamp">
         <cost>700</cost>
         <category>2</category>
         <type>3</type>
      </item>
   </items>
</itemdata>
```

And my Code in C# looks like this:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("c:/dir/itemdata.xml");

foreach(XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("//item/@name")) {
   string innerText = node.InnerText;
}
```

How could I display for example the Attributes "cost" or "type" within the same foreach loop?

Comment: `cost` and `type` are child nodes, not attributes. I would iterate over `document.SelectNodes("//item")` and get the attribute and node values as needed (via `node.SelectSingleNode()` or `node.Attributes` and/or `node.Children`.

Comment: What have you tried besides opening the document, what is your code, what did work, what did not work? Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: another approach would be to de-serialize the xml into a type, then play  with the object in c# rather than xpath

Comment: I tried some ways but all didn't worked well, got few times a NullReferenceException. I would actually stay at the same foreach loop if its possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    foreach(XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("//item")) {
        var cost = node.SelectSingleNode("./cost").InnerText;
        var type = node.SelectSingleNode("./type").InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(cost);
        Console.WriteLine(type);
    }
```

Comment: Thats seems to solved it, its also a nice example how it should look like, didn't knew how to use that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using LINQ to XML API, available in the .Net Framework since 2007. No need to use somewhat outdated XML API.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filename = @"e:\Temp\itemdata.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

    var Item = xdoc.Descendants("item");

    foreach (var elem in Item.Elements())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{elem.Name}='{elem.Value}'");
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this uses LINQ to XML, a different technology than the OP's `XmlDocument`.